# Form action value difference in prop and attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Here is a simple form:

```
<form action="hello">

</form>
```

If I use

```
var action = $('form').attr('action');
```

I get the correct value, "hello".
But if I use

```
var action = $('form').prop('action');
```

I get

```
http://localhost/hello
```

What's up with that?

I read that I should use prop() instead of of attr() but here it returns incorrect value

Comment: how about `var action = document.form.action`?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin `document.forms[0].action` then. And it will return absolute path.

Comment: Who told you to use `prop` and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say `prop`, it will get the absolute path of the target resource but `.attr()` will read the attribute value as it is.

Since you have used relative path in the action, `prop` will use the path of the current page to construct the actual url to which the form will be submitted.

Comment: does it persist only to the `action` attribute? What is i request `$('form').prop('class')`, seems it should return actual attribute value, shouldn't it?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin this happens to only special attributes.... the `href` of an anchor element is another attribute which displays similar behavior